# Symfony - Override sf_format when calling get_partial

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm making an AJAX call in my symfony project, so it has an sf_format of 'js'. In the actionSuccess.js.php view, I call get_partial to update the content on the page. By default it looks for the partial in 'js' format since the sf_format is still set as 'js'. Is it possible to override the sf_format so that it uses the regular 'html' partial that I already have (so that I don't have to have two identical partials)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar issue.

I looked through the code, and get_partial doesn't give you any scope to change the format looked for ... guess you could modify the code to make that possible if you needed to.

I instead went for switching the request format - also not ideal in my opinion. But better than editing the symfony files.

To do this in the controller:

```
$request->setRequestFormat('html');
```

or in the view

```
$sf_context->getRequest()->setRequestFormat('html');
```

In both cases, if you want to set this back afterwards, you can retrieve the existing value using getRequestFormat().

Comment: Awesome, Ben! Thanks! I'm setting the request format in the view, and it's actually simpler to call $sf_request->setRequestFormat('html') instead of using $sf_context.

Comment: ah yeah, my bad, the $sf_request helper is a neat shortcut, forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

if your looking for a more sustainable solution, you could listen to the `view.configure_format` and set the sfPHPView extension in your appflication configuration.

```
// in apps/api/config/apiConfiguration.class.php
public function configure() {
  $this->dispatcher->connect('view.configure_format', array($this, 'configure_formats'));
}

public function configure_formats(sfEvent $event) {
  // change extension, so our module templates and partials 
  // for xml do not need the .xml.php extension
  $event->getSubject()->setExtension('.php');
}
```